# Problem Getting an input from user in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

**Hey**
How I am supposed to input a string from a user in Discord.py. I am getting errors while trying to get input from user. It would be great if someone can help me :)

```html
import discord
from discord import embeds
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import time

client = discord.Client()
embed = discord.Embed()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')




@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('.gdrive'):
        first_embed = discord.Embed(title="Unlimited Google Drive Storage", color=0x2bff00)
        new_embed = discord.Embed(title='Made by zSupremeSniper0 & toxicXvoid', color=0x2bff00)
        new_embed2 = discord.Embed(title='Please Enter your gmail', color=0x2bff00)
       

# send a first message with an embed
        msg = await message.channel.send(embed=first_embed)

# edit the embed of the message
        time.sleep(5)
        await msg.edit(embed=new_embed)
        time.sleep(5)
        await msg.edit(embed=new_embed2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) to wait for a user input:

```
# edit the embed of the message
        time.sleep(5)
        await msg.edit(embed=new_embed)
        time.sleep(5)
        await msg.edit(embed=new_embed2)

        def check(m):
          return m.channel == message.channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await message.channel.send("OK")
```